# error MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"

Tags: express, mongoose

i'm facing this error
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
while trying to connect to mongoose

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
})
.then(()=>{
    console.log('db connected')
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
})

app.listen(8800,()=>{
    console.log('backend server is running')
})
```

Comment: Maybe the file is called `env` instead of `.env`?

Comment: i checked it its .env

Comment: Have you logged `process.env.MONGO_URL` to your console? Does it output the expected URL?

Comment: i surpassed that problem it gives me this error : bad authentication : authentication failed

Comment: i fixed the error , thank you

Comment: You shouldn't post your connection string with your real url, you don't want people getting a hold of that.